# Нужны ли запятые при таком построении предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Теперь же происходят непонятные для моего ума вещи.

Мой вариант.

*Теперь же происходят, непонятные для моего ума, вещи.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятые не нужны. Определительный оборот "непонятные для моего ума" стоит перед определеляемым словом. Если бы он стоял после определеляемого слова, то запятая бы ставилась: *Теперь же происходят вещи, непонятные для моего ума*.

Вот что пишет об этом Розенталь:

> Как правило, обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) согласованные распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависимыми от них словами и стоящие после определяемого слова, например: Тополи, покрытые росой, наполняли воздух нежным ароматом (Чехов); Бледный свет, похожий на чуть разбавленную синькой воду, заливал восточную часть горизонта (Паустовский).
>
> Примечание. Не обособляются согласованные распространенные определения:
>
> а)       стоящие перед определяемым существительным (если не имеют добавочных обстоятельственных оттенков значения, см. ниже, п. 6), например: Вышедший рано утром отряд прошел уже четыре версты (Л. Толстой);

([§92. Обособленные согласованные и несогласованные определения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#%D0%B7_01))